# ZUUL Dynamic Routing with Eureka

Tags: netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

I have a zuul pre filter:

```
@Override
public Object run() {
    // read authenticated User from session
    RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
    AuthenticatedUser authUser = SessionUtil.getAuthUser();
    if (authUser == null) {
        // if not logged in
        // route to login service
    }
    // if logged in
    // add additional headers to requests
    return null;
}
```

So in this filter, I first see if the request is authenticated. If not, I want to re-direct it to a `login` service in Eureka and then after the user logs in, he should be forwarded to the service he originally requested.

ZUUL config is like:

```
zuul:
  ignoredServices: '*'
  routes:
    service1:
      path: /s1/**
      serviceId: ${env}.s1
      stripPrefix: false
    service2:
      path: /s2/**
      serviceId: ${env}.s2
      stripPrefix: false
    login:
      path: /login/**
      sensitiveHeaders:
      serviceId: ${env}.login

eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://hostname:8761/eureka/
eureka.instance.non-secure-port-enabled=true
```

Basically, I'd like to know how I can do the routing with Eureka in the filter code.

**EDIT:**

I think a better design might be just to redirect to zuul itself: get the host and append `/login`. So the zuul routing settings in `yml` will take effect. I still wonder how to do it, and then forward the request to its original destination.